# 'This' scope in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, this

On my webpage I have remove icons on rows in a table like this:

[image]

I am using TypeScript where I have attached an `onClick` listener to execute a function called `OnRemoveClick`, like this `$('.remove').click(this.OnRemoveClick);`

`OnRemoveClick` zeros 2 fields (on the row the remove icon is clicked) and then executes 2 functions, like this:

```
private OnRemoveClick(): void {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.input-qty').val('0');
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.sub-total').html('0');
    this.GetInputFieldsToJson();
    this.CalculateTotal();
}
```

The problem I have is that it falls over when I get to `GetInputFieldsToJson` I get:

> TypeError: this.GetInputFieldsToJson is not a function at
>   HTMLAnchorElement.Index.OnRemoveClick

I realise it is because `this` in the context of `OnRemoveClick` is attached to the `HTMLAnchorElement` which means I cannot access my functions from there.

**What I have tried**

I have tried setting the onClick listener with a lambda expression like this:

`$('.remove').click(() => this.OnRemoveClick);`

but that means that the two jQuery expressions to zero fields on the row no longer work

Comment: `$('.remove').click(this.OnRemoveClick.bind(this));` then  `private OnRemoveClick(e): void { $(e.currentTarget).parents()...  }`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Comment: @Arun P Johny's answer is correct. This should work as well $('.remove').click(() => this.OnRemoveClick())

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny, this works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you might have already understood, the problem here is, when the event handler is invoked the default context as the dom element which triggered that event. So you are unable to invoke your object's method using that reference.

There are multiple solutions to this problem, one easy solution is to pass a custom context to the callback function using Function.bind() as given below and access the targeted element using `Event.currentTarget` in the callback like

```
private OnRemoveClick(e): void {
    $(e.currentTarget).parents('tr').find('.input-qty').val('0');
    $(e.currentTarget).parents('tr').find('.sub-total').html('0');
    this.GetInputFieldsToJson();
    this.CalculateTotal();
}
```

then

```
$('.remove').click(this.OnRemoveClick.bind(this));
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('.remove').click(() => this.OnRemoveClick);` should be `$('.remove').click(() => this.OnRemoveClick());` i.e. *call the function*.

More on `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: I'm not sure you've taken the time to understand my question, this isn't helpful at all

Comment: The accepted answer `$('.remove').click(this.OnRemoveClick.bind(this));` and what I have said `$('.remove').click(() => this.OnRemoveClick());` are fundamentally equivalent. This is why I am pointing you to gather a better understanding of `this` otherwise you will run into this issue again without understanding what is actually happening